# How to bind a Silverlight Toolkit DataGrid cell value to a TextBlock or TextBox text property

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-toolkit

I need to implement a master/details `View`, having a `DataGrid` as a master and quite probably `TextBlock` or `TextBox` components displaying details for each row field -- despite I'm aware about the `DataForm` component I'm not exactly sure that would be the solution given that currently I'm not requited to support CRUD operations over that data.

So the problem is basically how to bind each `DataGridTextColumn` to a particular `Text` property of any given control (e.g. `TextBlock`) having its values uptated when a different row is selected.

The `XAML` code would look something like this:

```
<!-- Master -->

<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="FoobarDataGrid" DataContext="foobar" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="FooDataGridColumn" Header="Foo" Binding="{Binding Foo}" />
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BarDataGridColumn" Header="Bar" Binding="{Binding Bar}" />
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>

<!-- Details -->

<TextBox x:Name="FooDetailsTextBlock" Text="{Binding <!-- TODO -->}" />
<TextBox x:Name="BarDetailsTextBlock" Text="{Binding <!-- TODO -->}" />
```

Don't hesitate to ask for any other detail as every bit of advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED:** Here is what your code would look like...

```
<!-- Master -->

<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="FoobarDataGrid" DataContext="foobar" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="FooDataGridColumn" Header="Foo" Binding="{Binding Foo}" />
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BarDataGridColumn" Header="Bar" Binding="{Binding Bar}" />
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>

<!-- Details -->

<TextBox 
    DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=FoobarDataGrid}"
    x:Name="FooDetailsTextBlock" 
    Text="{Binding Foo}" />

<TextBox 
    DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=FoobarDataGrid}"
    x:Name="BarDetailsTextBlock" 
    Text="{Binding Bar}" />
```

**Original Answer...**

Here is a way...

My `DataGrid` is bound to a collection of a custom class.  That class has a property called `LabName`.  This is what I bind to a column in the `DataGrid`

XAML

```
    <sdk:DataGrid 
        Name="LabsDataGrid" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        Height="284" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="205,250,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="359" 
        IsReadOnly="True">

        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Lab Name" 
                Binding="{Binding LabName}" />

        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

    </sdk:DataGrid>


    <TextBox 
        DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=LabsDataGrid}"
        Name="LabName" 
        Text="{Binding LabName}"
        Height="23" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="324,121,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="132" />
```

Notice that I am setting the `DataContext` of the `TextBox` to the `SelectedItem` of the `DataGrid`.  So when the user clicks a row in the `DataGrid`, the `TextBox` is populated with the `LabName` that is bound to the column in the `DataGrid`.

Comment: thanks much for the contribution, that's a quite interesting approach.

Comment: I've slightly edited the markup: wrapped TextBox components within a Grid to avoid declaring a DataContext property for each element. Thanks much!

Comment: @Nano: I think I will go edit my code to do that also.  Never dawned on me to do that.